# The height of <use> tag is always 0 while I am trying to exploit an external SVG file

Tags: html, svg

Here's my html file where I am trying to make the icon displayable:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="icons.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg
      role="img"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      viewBox="0 0 32 32"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      >
      <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-phoneaparat" style="overflow: hidden" />
      </svg>
      </body>
      </html>
```

The SVG file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l5ixCUR9SKXPf5v7k96tyzD6YExgo_JI/view

Comment: Are you running these two files from a webserver or from the file system? Given that the code is correct this only works when served from a webserver.

Comment: I applied file system exclusively. I'll try out your idea soon.